# Excel VBA change based on pull down list

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a few Excel formulas that change data in columns E & G based on the info entered into columns C & D. Column F needed to be a static time stamp so I had to use a simple VBA script for it. The formulas are a little long and unwieldy, and other people work on the workbook, so I tried scripting E & G through VBA to lower the risk of the formulas getting messed up.

I'm not quite the best when it comes to VBA, and after numerous failed attempts, I've ended up with what just ends up crashing Excel.

The following is my latest attempt;

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 4 Then
        Cells(Target.Row, 6).Value = Now
    End If
    If Target.Column = 4 And Cells(Target.Row, 4).Value = "Daily" Then
            Cells(Target.Row, 5).Value = [INDIRECT("C" & ROW())+28]
        ElseIf Target.Column = 4 And Cells(Target.Row, 4).Value = "Weekly" Then
            Cells(Target.Row, 5).Value = [INDIRECT("C" & ROW())+49]
        Else: Cells(Target.Row, 5).Value = "---"
   End If
End Sub
```

I also have the following which I haven't tried due to the other part crashing;

```
If Target.Column = 4 And (Cells(Target.Row, 4).Value = "Daily" OR Cells(Target.Row, 4).Value = "Weekly") Then
        Cells(Target.Row, 7).Value = [WORKDAY(INDIRECT(""E"" & ROW()),-1]
    Else  Cells(Target.Row, 7).Value = "---"
End If
```

And the Excel formulas;

```
=IF(INDIRECT("D" & ROW())<>"",CHOOSE(IF(INDIRECT("D" & ROW())="Daily",1,IF(INDIRECT("D" & ROW())="Weekly",2,3)),INDIRECT("C" & ROW())+28,INDIRECT("C" & ROW())+49,"---"),"")

=IF(INDIRECT("D" & ROW())<>"",CHOOSE(IF(OR(INDIRECT("D" & ROW())="Daily",INDIRECT("D" & ROW())="Weekly"),1,2),WORKDAY(INDIRECT("E" & ROW()),-1),"---"),"")
```

I've tried recording a macro of the formulas and copying the code from there into the VBA code, but that didn't work either.

I said it in the title, but forgot to mention in the body; Column D is a drop down list, Column C is a date that the user enters.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is not bad, but the *structure* of the event macro needs improvement.  For this kind of event we need:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'if Target is NOT of interest, then exit
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        'perform your logic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This prevents the macro from stepping on its own tail.

This is a better schema **(untested)**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column <> 4 Then Exit Sub
    Dim v As String
    v = Target.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Offset(0, 2).Value = Now
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = "'----"
        If v = "Daily" Then
            'insert formula
        End If
        If v = "Weekly" Then
            'insert formula
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

On a separate issue is having **VBA** insert a formula.  Here the schema is like:

```
Cells(3,7).Formula="=1+2"
```

*There may be other problems.*